# SHA1 digest compare with String fingerprint in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sha1

I have a string representation of web-site's fingerprint:

`5D A8 E2 8A F7 D7 82 65 40 14 8C 8A 3C 4B 37 49 CE A4 B2 42`

Then I need to match it with the certificate's hash, which I'm using CryptoKit for:

```
static func sha1FingerprintsForTrust(_ trust: SecTrust) -> [String] {
    var sha1s: [String] = []
    for index in 0..<SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trust) {
        if let certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, index) {
            let der = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate) as NSData
            let sha1 = Insecure.SHA1.hash(data: der)
            print(sha1) //prints **SHA1 digest: 76e27ec14fdb82c1c0a675b505be3d29b4eddbbb**
        }
    }
    return sha1s
}
```

how can I convert any of those to match it with the other? Either way: Insecure.SHA1.Digest into String or String into Digest to then compare them?

Side note: I am aware that SHA1 is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @Larme indeed, in the end I need to find a matching sha1 in the array of sha1s

Comment: I'm not familiar with these lib, but I guess that there are method available there https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/insecure/sha1digest `iterator` that could help you get a hexa representation string of the data, and then you can use it to compare.

Answer (score 1):

As usual the answer is pretty simple:

```
sha1.hexString
```

That's the missing thing I was looking for. With that I get a String and the only thing left is to make format of those same (remove spaces and turn `uppercased()`) and then compare them.